# Can't install operators outside of `openshift-marketplace`

Tags: kubernetes-operator

Attempting to install an Operator into a single namespace `foobar` results in the error:

`Operator Group does not support single namespace installation mode`.

Attempting to install an Operator into all namespaces into the `openshift-operators` namespace results in the error:

`The namespace 'openshift-operators' does not support install modes for this operator`

Configuring Operator Groups doesn't change anything.

In any case, operators can't be installed outside of `openshift-marketplace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue (and many others) is caused by having multiple instances of the Operator Lifecycle Manager (OLM) installed.
OpenShift has an instance of OLM already installed, called `openshift-operator-lifecycle-manager`

This is an easy mistake to for beginners to Operators, because the `operator-sdk olm` command, which is recommended by the Operator SDK tutorials, can't seem to detect other forks of OLM.

[Deleting the extra OLM](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/tasks/uninstall-olm/) will solve the problem.